# WP8 update pivot title from other class

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I just can't figure out how to fix this... I'd like to update MainPage pivot title from other class. I have method in MainPage that does it and it obviously works fine when doing the update inside MainPage but obviously it doesn't do anything when I call the MainPage method from the other class.

So basically the situation is this for the class:

```
MainPage mp = new MainPage();
mp.UpdateTitle();
```

and the MainPage:

```
public void UpdateTitle()
{
  Pivotname.Title = App.somevalue;
}
```

That obviously doesn't work. What would be the best solution for updating page's pivot title from any class? I'm really new to WP8 development and I just can't seem to figure out solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with static reference of `MainPage` and use it in another class.

```
public static MainPage CurrentMainPage;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CurrentMainPage = this;
}
```

From another class

```
MainPage.CurrentMainPage.UpdateTitle();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! So obvious... Oh well.

Comment: hi xyroid, can you help me in following question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216367/how-to-refresh-the-data-in-pivot-item-after-update-data-through-usercontrol?noredirect=1#comment33732020_22216367